# Display bigger image on click

Tags: javascript, php, gallery

I am trying to make gallery page and when I click on image, it will go bigger and then arrows shows on both sides and you can click them and display next and previous pictures. Can you please help me how to do it? I don't know JavaScript language also I would like to ask if I should change anything in my code?

```
<div class="main-outer">
<div class="content">
    <div class="novinky full">
        <h1 class="title" id="title">Gallery</h1>
        <div class="article-full">
            <div id="pages-viewer" class="viewer" style="visibility: visible;">
                <div class="toastui-editor-contents" style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">
                    <div class="">
                        <form action="" method="get">
                            <p>Category: </p>
                            <select id="category" name="category" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                <option value="all" <?= $sort_by == 'all' ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Všetky</option>
                                <?php foreach ($categories as $c) : ?>
                                    <option value="<?= $c['title'] ?>" <?= $category == $c['title'] ? ' selected' : '' ?>><?= $c['title'] ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </select>
                            <p>Sort by: </p>
                            <select id="sort_by" name="sort_by" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                <option value="z_to_a" <?= $sort_by == 'z_to_a' ? ' selected' : '' ?>>A-Z</option>
                                <option value="a_to_z" <?= $sort_by == 'a_to_z' ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Z-A</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-list">
                        <?php foreach ($media as $m) : ?>
                            <?php if (file_exists($m['thumbnailpath'])) : ?>
                                <div style="width:<?= $imgwidth ?>px;height:<?= $imgheight ?>px; margin-bottom: 100px; margin-left: 11px; margin-right: 11px;">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="<?= $m['thumbnailpath'] ?>" alt="<?= $m['title'] ?>" data-id="<?= $m['id'] ?>" data-title="<?= $m['title'] ?>" max-width="<?= $imgwidth ?>" height="<?= $imgheight ?>" style="align: center; max-height: <?= $imgheight ?>"></a>
                                    <div style="text-align:center; font-size:25px; font-weight: bold;">
                                        <p><?= substr($m['title'], 0, 23); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="text-align:center;"><?= substr($m['rok'], 0, 15); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to look at http://chocolat.insipi.de.
It's a free cross browser JavaScript library that handles switching images.

Comment: If the OP was looking for a recommendation for a gallery library, then the question would be off-topic for StackOverflow and should be closed as such...

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite gallery and it's easy to use.

https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js/

Comment: If the OP was looking for a recommendation for a gallery library, then the question would be off-topic for StackOverflow and should be closed as such...